# creating jasper report using map data source spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I want to create a jasper report. I am passing following data source.

```
Collection<Map<String, String>> listCollection = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

//value insertion in listCollection

JRDataSource ds= new JRMapCollectionDataSource(listCollection);
Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
parameterMap.put("datasource", ds);
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("xlsReport", parameterMap);
```

Now, I want to get the values from this map in jrxml file through keys. I am using spring model and view.

Want to use something like that

```
<![CDATA[$P{datasource}.get("key")]]
```

in jrxml file inside textField.

Answer (score 1):

your data source should like this

```
    JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listCollection);   

    model.addAttribute("datasourcebmireportA", datasource);

    model.addAttribute("datasource", "pdf");

    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("xlsReport", parameterMap);
```

i'm not sure what you were asking but [check this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791298/jasperreports-with-maven-and-eclipse-example/24794799#24794799)