# How can I create a report (jasperreport) from a List<MyObject>?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have already created the report (report1.jrxml) copiled it (report1.jasper) and I just want to fill it with the info of this list: `List<MyObject>`

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private int phone;
    //getters & setters...
}
```

The data of the list has been retrieved from a database so I want to use the info of the list to fill the report.

I want to create a pdf.

Please help me.

Comment: [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources)

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about passing a collection from java code to jasperreports, the best way is to use:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
```

**EDIT:**

Full example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
JRBeanCollectionDataSource jDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(objects);

// Load report
ClassPathResource report = new ClassPathResource("/myReport.jasper");
InputStream input = report.getInputStream();

// Fill the report with data
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(input);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, jDataSource);

// Export the report to the output
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
exporter.exportReport();

// Return the byte[]
return output.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: [see this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791298/jasperreports-with-maven-and-eclipse-example/24794799#24794799)

Answer (score 0):

Heres the relevant code:

```
List<MyObject> list//list contains the data used to fill report
JasperDesign design=JRXmlLoader.load(file);//file is your .jrxml file or .jasper file
JasperReport report==JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
JasperPrint print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,parameter,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
```

Now you can use `print` object to export the report to required format.
Hope it helps.